# Unusual Build Error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-studio

I have compiled my code and getting this single error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':iMSDroid:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\pardeep.sharma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Android\Android_Workspace\imsdroid\iMSDroid\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\Android\Android_Workspace\imsdroid\iMSDroid\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/doubango/ngn/NgnApplication;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

My Build.Gradle file contains the following

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-

projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and I've removed some of Special character from Comments and Correct SDK installation path but got no luck. Please see if there's something unusual.

Update :

Imsdroid Build.gradle file code :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.doubango.imsdroid"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 11
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidngnstack')
}
```

Comment: Post the build.gradle in your app folder not the project folder, it will help to identify the problem. Right now it seems that two of the libraries you are importing use NgnApplication so this creates the duplicate error in dex merger

Comment: try to build from command line once.

Comment: I tried using command prompt but no success. I am able build / make project , but while Clicking on Run Button it pop up with errors.